# I try to show order history when user successfully checkout items but the image is not showing in the order history

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, checkout, asyncstorage

```
  const getCart = async () => {
    const cartItem = await AsyncStorage.getItem("checkoutItems");
    console.log("cart", cartItem);
    if (cartItem) {
      setCheckout(JSON.parse(cartItem));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCart();
  }, []);

 
      {checkout.map((item, index) => (
        <View key={index}>
          {item.productImage ? (
            <Image
              source={{ uri: item.productImage.toString() }}
              style={{ width: 50, height: 20 }}
              onError={(error) => console.log("Error loading image:", error)}
            />
          ) : (
            <Text>No image available</Text>
          )}
          <Text>{item.productName}</Text>
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
```

Here I save the details of the checkout products in AsyncStorage. The issue is when I try to show the image with name it will not show the image ,it is save as a array in asyncstorage. Here is my code where i try to show the order history